# find_element_by_class_name for multiple classes

Tags: python, django, api, selenium, parsing

Selenium in the API for Python / Django has the function driver.find_element/elements_by_class_name (), but it is not written whether it can be used for several classes
I need choose element with several classes like bj,bd,bi
If possible, how?

Comment: use find_elements_by_class_name.

Comment: Did you try it? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Yes, i try it. Different things. But I thought that there might be some function / reception not described in the documentation.

Comment: You can use a loop and use .format() to get each class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is No, You can't use `driver.find_element_by_class_name ()` or `driver.find_elements_by_class_name ()` with multiple class names. It accepts only single class name.

However, you can use `find_elements_by_xpath` or `find_element_by_css_selector` method to achieve finding element with multiple class names.

for example below code will find element on google website using two different class names.

```
url= "http://google.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='sfibbbc' or @class='jsb']")
# Following line will result in error 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sfibbbc jsb")
```

Comment: I love programming for this. Tried only through classes and all. But it's even easier with xpath. Thank you

Comment: I find it's more concise with css selector (of course 
 I'm with java )...findElements(By.cssSelector(".sfibbbc.jsb"))

Comment: FYI @1234's suggestion in python is the following: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(". sfibbbc. jsb")`