# Using find_elements_by_xpath for two conditions to scrape src using OR in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am scraping images from a website, but the xpath varies for the element. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes) that an or function can be used by doing find_elements_by_xpath.

However, when I tried replicating the example, I could no longer extract the src of the image. Am I doing the or function wrong?

```
images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('// img[ @ id = "ember51"]' or '// img[@id="ember52"]')
print(images.get_attribute('src'))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

I attempted to make a for loop, so the src could be scraped:

```
images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('// img[ @ id = "ember51"]' or '// img[@id="ember52"]')
for image in images:
    print(images.get_attribute('src'))
```

But when I use a for loop, I get the same error. Not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `|` as or operator.

```
images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@id = "ember51"]|//img[@id="ember52"]')
```

[image]

Make sure the entire xpath is wrapped in `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid `xpath` expresion:

```
// img[ @ id = "ember51"]' or '// img[@id="ember52"]
```

It's should:

```
//img[@id="ember51" or @id="ember52"]
```

Try this:

```
images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@id="ember51" or @id="ember52"]')
for image in images:
    print(images.get_attribute('src'))
```