# How do I count the number of divs with a specific class using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building a selenium Bot to automatically play the  game [cookie clicker](https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)

And I am trying to access the buildings list since the buildings in this game get unlocked as I play and I want to make the computer is aware of the state of the buildings so that when it is about to buy a building it should start checking even the newly unlocked buildings and the way the game updates the buildings is by changing the class names from "product locked disabled" to "product unlocked disabled",

so I want to count how many classes have the unlocked name in them but the problem is the inner HTML of the div's are empty so when I use the `find_elements_by_class_name()` it returns an empty list, so is the way I can count the div's with a specific class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In selenium `find_elements_by_class_name` [accepts only one class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes), whereas your desired `div` has 3 - `product`, `locked`/`unlocked`, and `disabled`. You should consider using CSS selectors (or XPATHs) for this.

To find a `div` with the classes-

- `product`
- `locked`
- `disabled`
  using CSS selectors, you should use-

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.product.locked.disabled')
```

To find a `div` with the classes-

- `product`
- `unlocked`
- `disabled`
  using CSS selectors, you should use-

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.product.unlocked.disabled')
```