# How to click on the Create Account button within https://mail.protonmail.com/ signup page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Everything is working except the button. The submit button is not being clicked. Can anyone help me out? I believe it may have to do with the fact that I changed the frame to "top". But, I am unsure how to change it back.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = 'https://protonmail.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/edenhikri/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.btn.btn-default.btn-short'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.panel-heading'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#freePlan'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'password'))).send_keys('test123')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'passwordc'))).send_keys('test123')

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".top")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'username'))).send_keys('myUsername')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-submit').click()
```

error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn.btn-submit"}
```

button code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="submitBtn">Create Account</button>
```

I have also tried using xpath but I get the same error that it cannot find this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class=“btn btn-submit”]").click()
```

Comment: Is there an error, what happens? Have you checked the page source to ensure that the button is there?

Comment: I have edited. @AMC

Comment: Alright, what do you understand from that error message, then?

Comment: that it cannot locate the button from the class name. I am not sure of another way to find the button. I have inserted the button code. @AMC

Comment: _I have inserted the button code._ What do you mean? Have you checked the HTML source which the program ends up with to ensure that the element is what you expect?

Comment: Yes. Look at the edit. I inserted the button's code from the website @AMC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find\_element\_by\_class\_name for multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes)

Comment: Could you please also give the HTML code in case you are locating the button wrong

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal They already did, and their code looks like a [mcve] anyway.

Comment: I have added the HTML source code under "button code:" in my post. It is the right button. @SiddharthAgrawal

Comment: @AMC I have tried using xpath as noted In the answer you shared. It did not work.

Comment: @Eden The XPath in your post is for a different element entirely, no?

Comment: That is the xpath given when I press copy xpath on the html code for the button. @AMC

Comment: @Eden Wait never mind, it could work. Can you try using the XPath `//button[@class=“btn btn-submit”]` ?

Comment: I tried this `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class=“btn btn-submit”]').click()`. but it did not work. I go the error `The string '//button[@class=“btn btn-submit”]' is not a valid XPath expression.` @AMC

Comment: @Eden It might be the quotation marks, try rewriting them?

Comment: I tried rewriting. It did not fix it. @AMC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217577/discussion-between-eden-and-amc).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this xpath **//*[contains(text(),"Create Account")]**

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>CREATE ACCOUNT</kbd> button is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-default.btn-short[href='signup']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-plan='free']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#freePlan"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.top[title='Registration form']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("Eden")
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password"))).send_keys("Eden")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#passwordc").send_keys("Eden")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.bottom[title='Registration form']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-submit"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail_create_user]