# How to find log in button element or what element I should use in this scenario

Tags: python

How can I find the log in button element? My script as below but not working after input username & password. Or shall I use find element by css selector or other? and how?

```
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("cux-button ng-scope").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDTuh.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Selenium and the Selenium Python bindings. (Tipp: Mention the library, you are using, in your question. :) )

The `find_element_by_class_name()` method only allows searching for a single class name, as already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes). As mentioned in the answers to that question, you can use the `find_element_by_xpath()` or `find_element_by_css_selector()` methods for more complex queries.

In your scenario, CSS selectors are sufficiently powerfull, so let's use them:

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cux-button.ng-scope").click()
```

For understanding CSS selectors, you might want to take a look into [this tutorial by Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors), as recommended by the [unofficial Python Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors).