# Updating facebook post using Selenium: error- element not found but i can find in my browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to post on facebook wall using selenium in python. I am able to login but after login it cant find class name of status box which i copied from browser

here is my code-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

user_name = "email"
password = "password" 
msg = "hi i am new here"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
element.send_keys(user_name)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
element.send_keys(password)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)

post_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7")
post_box.click()
time.sleep(5)    
post_box.send_keys(msg)
```

the snapshot of code i copied from browser is attached as image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmZeX.png)

here is error i recived-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rosha/Desktop/facebook bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    post_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\facebook bot.py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\facebook bot.py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\facebook bot.py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\facebook bot.py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to find element by Xpath for example:

**driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')**
to find the xpath from the browser, just right click on something in the webpage and press inspect after that right click, a menu will appear, navigate to copy then another menu will appear, press copy fullpath.
check this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: It works. Thanks, but i've ran into another error. Since I didnt knew html, css much. After opening text field while trying to insert message via Send_keys(), it shows "Element <span> is not reachable by keyboard". I think i am not selecting correct element which is reachable by keyboard. can you help me here???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` can be used for one class, and not multiple classes as you have: `a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7` which are multiple classes separated by spaces.

Refer to the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760303/12106481), it suggests using `find_elements_by_xpath` or `find_element_by_css_selector`.

Comment: It works. Thanks, but i've ran into another error. Since I didnt knew html, css much. After opening text field while trying to insert message via Send_keys(), it shows "Element <span> is not reachable by keyboard". I think i am not selecting correct element which is reachable by keyboard. can you help me here???