# How to fix "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", find_element for selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, findelement

Previous questions are not solving this issue. It's 2022, questions from 2015 aren't helping. I've read previous TypeError:'str' questions on stack overflow and, believe it or not, they're not helping.

What I am trying to do is use find_element() to get the price($199.99) of this [21 in 1 pressure cooker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088384YYD) and then display it with the print function. However, I get this error when I run my code:

> line 10, in <module> price =
> driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('a-price aok-align-center
> reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay')) TypeError: 'str' object is
> not callable

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service("/Users/myname/Development/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Electric-Pressure-One-Touch/dp/B08CF8J3M8/ref=sr_1_10?crid=3HDJU6IJ0LN6Y&keywords=instant+pot+9+in+1+electric+pressure+cooker&qid=1656866250&sprefix=instant+pot+9+in+1+electric+pressure+cooker%2Caps%2C98&sr=8-10")

price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay'))
print(price.text)

driver.quit()
```

On this webpage, the price for this pressure cooker is displayed twice and I am trying to use the price displayed first (going from left to right) because when I right click and use **inspect**, the class name is unique, 1 of 1.

I have tried: `find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=etc)`

That didn't work.

This is a picture of the page from the above link. You can see the price to the pressure cooker is listed twice. I am trying to access the price on the left via the code from **inspect** (an option when you right click).

[image: Picture of Page from the above link]

Here you can see the span class is: `"a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay"`. This is the left price.

[image: Here you can see the span class is: a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay]

Here you can see that the span class is shorter than aforementioned one, it's also common throughout this code

[image]

TL:DR, I'm trying to use find_element() to get the price of this item and then display it using print()

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python) helpful be useful to look into.

Comment: Check documentation or the example you copied again. `By.CLASS_NAME` doesn't have parenthesis after it

Comment: When I remove the parenthesis I get this message: (raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay"}) @OneCricketeer

Comment: That doesn't help @SeanXie

Comment: You should post a question with the code that raises that `NoSuchElementException`.  It sounds like it's much closer to a working solution in that you're actually calling the function with valid arguments (i.e. not raising a `TypeError` or a `SyntaxError`), you're just not finding the element you're looking for.  Based on the exception message it seems like maybe there's an extra `.` character...?

Comment: I added a period in front of the "a". Before the code was `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay')`.** and now it's `(By.CLASS_NAME, '.a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay')`. Which confuses me because on the website there is no period there. Now the message is: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`. I am going to try all of the selectors one by one but it wouldn't make sense to me... to be anything besides `CLASS_NAME` @Samwise

Comment: Looks like maybe you can't specify multiple class names with `find_element`, but there are other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759907/find-element-by-class-name-for-multiple-classes

Comment: This is progress! I used `find_elements` instead and dropped the period in front of the "a" and the code ran. My only issue now is this line `print(price.text)` is giving me this message: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. I tried running this `for money in price: print(money.text)`. The code ran but the price didn't print out.

Comment: *see above message, forgot to tag you.*                                                                  
  also, when I run `print(price)`. I get an empty list. @Samwise

Comment: I can't see the actual code you're running.  Maybe post a new question with the current version of your code and the new problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Samwise I solved it, `price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corePrice_feature_div"]/div/span/span[2]')`. If I run this on price like $199.99(where 99 is smaller and in the air next to 199) the code will render $199 and then 99 on a new line. If I use pprint then it renders '$199\n99'. But I could just take those characters out and put in a period. Appreciate your time!! It helped a lot.